# Return BOOL for first occurance of file found in directory with Powershell

Tags: search, powershell

```
C:\docs

text1.txt
text2.txt
text3.txt
lol.txt
wut.txt
dudewut.txt
```

SEARCH "wut"

- I do not want a recursive solution.
- I do not want to return a file name.
- I just want to know if a file exhists from a function that returns a
  bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Test-Path c:\docs\*wut* -PathType Leaf`

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Im tyring to search for file name as a string

Comment: and how do you use * and what does it do before after and both?

Comment: It indicates that it should only return true for **files**.  If there is a **directory** named "wut", then this will return false.

Comment: `*` is a wildcard.  So any file with a name *containing* "wut" will cause this to return true.  To match any `.txt` file, you would use `C:\docs\*.txt`, etc.  If you only want to look for an explicit full file name, then just put that in: `C:\docs\wut.txt` or maybe `C:\docs\wut.*`

Comment: so \*wut\* is any occurance whether it be wut.txt or txt.wut?

Comment: Correct.  If you want to restrict it to "a file named exactly 'wut' with any extension" then use `C:\docs\wut.*`  This is standard Windows wildcard logic.

Answer (score 1):

@latkin has the right idea, just use a wildcarded path e.g.:

```
Test-Path wut*
```

or

```
Test-Path C:\Docs\*wut*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileExhists = Get-ChildItem C:\docs -Recurse -Include *.* | Select-String wut
```

I can then do something like:

```
if(!$fileExhists){}
```

But this isnt really what I want. This is recursive and doesn't return a bool.

Comment: Just remove the `-Recurse` switch

Comment: Actually, no this is not at all what you want.  This will search the **contents** of the files for "wut", not the file names.